# Excel column (distinct) write into CASE statement

Tags: excel, distinct, case-statement

I have columns called `Project`, `Status`, `Color`. Each row under `Project` is unique, however, the status can be `Approved`, `Rejected`, `Submitted`, etc and there is a unique color for each status type (ie. Approved is green).

On another sheet, I need to be able to create a case statement that selects each distinct status type (more could be added, so it needs to be dynamic) and output it in a format like this:

```
CASE WHEN "Project"."Current Status" = 'Submitted' THEN '#008000'
WHEN "Project"."Current Status" = 'In Progress' THEN  '#F1E87D'
WHEN "Project"."Current Status" = 'Rejected' THEN '#CD0000'
WHEN "Project"."Current Status" = 'Approved' THEN '#0000EB'
Else "Project"."Current Status" END
```

Where it puts in the status types for me with the corresponding color.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this ..

```
SELECT CASE "Project"."Current Status" 
  Case Is 'Submitted': '#008000'
  Case Is 'In Progress': '#F1E87D'
  Case Is 'Rejected': '#CD0000'
  Case Is 'Approved': '#0000EB'

  CaseElse: 'WhatEver ..
END SELECT
```